# Keep the AppBar static when Navigating to a new screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to keep the AppBar static AppBar when navigating to a new screen. Something similar on this video where the green AppBar keeps static even when pushing a new screen.

[sample video](https://files.fm/f/3zhsgsd7j)

I'm still very new in Flutter and would like to know what would be the best approach to achieve this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: here https://newbedev.com/persisting-appbar-drawer-across-all-pages-flutter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Navigator` widget which let you create **nested navigation** in your main view (where the main navbar is).

Here is an **example** directly from Flutter website: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/nested-nav